# Hard wiping Linux laptop to fix Wifi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, laptop, bios, wipe

Some time ago I booted my laptop up and for some reason my WiFi stopped working... F9 nor the WiFi switch and button seem to respond anymore no matter how or which order I press them. Messed with settings in the BIOs, did some hardware scans, looked up solutions specifically for Linux... I tried everything I knew I could do, and now I'm at a complete loss.

[image: WiFi signal not lighting up]
[image: WiFi switch and button]

It's an older laptop, Dell Latitude XT2 that I installed Linux Mint 18.2 onto. I can't tell if it's a hardware issue or a software one. I don't know if I slightly dinged something out of place somehow without realizing, or if I sudo'd too many times not knowing what I'm doing. What I'm about to suggest is probably bollocks, so feel free to correct me or just break me the bad news.

So, I thought maybe I should just wipe the whole thing through and through, somehow wipe/reset the BIOS or whatever too just to make sure? I still have my boot of Linux and I saved all my personal settings and such elsewhere, so I'm willing to just try this as my last resort.

If I do wipe it, any tips on the best way to go about it? It's been a while since I've done it so I'm not sure how I did it anymore.

```
 ~ $ rfkill --version
rfkill 0.5-1ubuntu3.1 (Ubuntu)
 ~ $ rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
 ~ $ rfkill unblock 0
 ~ $ rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

 ~ $ iwlwifi
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

iwlwifi: command not found
 ~ $ lsmod | grep iwlwifi
 ~ $ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:ba:db:c7:b0:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 ~ $ wlp*
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

wlp*: command not found
 ~ $ iwconfig wlp
wlp       No such device
```

*Linux noob, still barely know what I'm doing.

Turned on the WiFi switch and reset everything, WiFi still not working...

Comment: It is unlikely (but not impossible)  that reinstalling the same version of Ubuntu will fix your problem.

Comment: The WiFi switch seems to be in the off position in the picture. Are you sure you tried with the slide switch in the on position? Accidentally using the RF kill switch is probably the most common cause of WiFi suddenly failing.

Comment: Linux problems can usually be fixed without reinstalling, there are no weird settings buried into an intractable registry. Maybe your Wifi interface is dead, in which case reinstalling won't fix it anyway. Let's take the problem from the beginning, have you got the `iwlwifi` module loaded (`lsmod | grep iwlwifi`)? Have you got a wifi interface in Linux (`ip link show`, search for `wlp*`)? If so what says `iwconfig wlp...`? (answer by editing your initial question). Of course set your Wifi button to "on" (and maybe reboot after setting it to "on").

Comment: Does WiFi work when you boot from a Linux LiveUSB? If you, you know it's not hardware.

Comment: Haha, it's been so long I forgot which side of the switch was on and off. But as mentioned I have tried it every which way, yes.

Okay, I tried your solutions as best I could. Turns out the RF kill was activated partly, so disabled it. Then I attempted xenoid's solutions but I'm such a noob still I don't know how to do things unless the exact code is given to me to copy paste.
I shutdown and turned on the PC with the WiFi switch on, pressed the button beside it and F9, but still nothing.

LiveUSB? Can I just use my boot USB or do I have to change it somehow?

Comment: If you installed from a live session, just boot up the live session on USB or DVD as you originally did.  See if it works from there.

Comment: Live session? That's the USB, right? I'm not familiar with these terms, sorry. Are you suggesting I reboot the whole laptop like was suggested earlier probably won't work? Or like, suggesting there's some way to boot directly from the USB without installing it onto a partition? Actually I just realized, maybe my own terminology hasn't been correct these past few posts...

Comment: "Booting from USB" means installing the OS onto the computer into one of its partitions right? Or does it mean using the USB as an external OS that can be accessed through the PC? Maybe this is a bit off topic now. ^^;

Comment: No, some form of "install" means to install. To boot merely means to start the computer and have it boot (load software from) the designated location, in this case, the USB. Most linux flavors have a "live" version which allows you to run a more or less fully featured OS just from the memory stick or DVD disc, with everything lost when you restart the computer. This is handy for testing things to sort out whether the problem is hardware (it has the same problem in the Live mode) or software (the problem is fixed in the live mode).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the explanation. I'm not sure if I can use what's installable from my USB as a Live OS, so I'll be sure to look up a Live version of Mint some time during this week and will report back. Thank you all for the help! :)

Comment: You mention that what you installed is Mint.  What Mint provides is a live session that includes the ability to install Mint from it.  You can simply boot from the USB and run from there (although a lot of features are disabled because it lacks the ability to save changes).  It's like booting from an external drive, but what loads in this case is a limited version.  The idea of a live session is to allow you to explore the "look and feel" of Mint and do some basic things without having to install it first.

Comment: Welp, guys, I booted from my USB with the wifi on and tried all the button combinations, but the wifi still didn't work. I guess it's a done deal? I could look into getting it repaired, but past experiences tell me it's much cheaper to just get a new one. Which I should do anyway since it's too outdated for some software I use. Either way, thank you all for all the help and tips! :)